# How to add textVIew to camera Previw

Tags: android, camera, zbar

Im developing application that is using Zbar qr code scanner. Everthing works fine, but I want to add some text to camera preview and Im unable to do it. When I add the text the camera preview disappear. There is not enought information about this and Id really appriciate if someone help me. Thanks !

this is the code of the my CameraPreview.java that looks like will make the magic

```
package com.dm.zbar.android.scanner;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.AutoFocusCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

class CameraPreview extends ViewGroup implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private final String TAG = "CameraPreview";

    SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    Size mPreviewSize;
    List<Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
    Camera mCamera;
    PreviewCallback mPreviewCallback;
    AutoFocusCallback mAutoFocusCallback;

    CameraPreview(Context context, PreviewCallback previewCallback, AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCb) {
        super(context);

        mPreviewCallback = previewCallback;
        mAutoFocusCallback = autoFocusCb;
        mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);


        TextView tvtest = new TextView(context);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,0);
        tvtest.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        tvtest.setText("Сканирайте QR !");
        addView(tvtest);




        addView(mSurfaceView);

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
        mCamera = camera;
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            requestLayout();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // We purposely disregard child measurements because act as a
        // wrapper to a SurfaceView that centers the camera preview instead
        // of stretching it.
        final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

        if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
            mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {

        if (changed && getChildCount() > 0) {
            final View child = getChildAt(0);

            final int width = r - l;
            final int height = b - t;

            int previewWidth = width;
            int previewHeight = height;
            if (mPreviewSize != null) {
                previewWidth = mPreviewSize.width;
                previewHeight = mPreviewSize.height;
            }

            // Center the child SurfaceView within the parent.
            if (width * previewHeight > height * previewWidth) {
                final int scaledChildWidth = previewWidth * height / previewHeight;
                child.layout((width - scaledChildWidth) / 2, 0,
                        (width + scaledChildWidth) / 2, height);
            } else {
                final int scaledChildHeight = previewHeight * width / previewWidth;
                child.layout(0, (height - scaledChildHeight) / 2,
                        width, (height + scaledChildHeight) / 2);
            }
        }
    }

    public void hideSurfaceView() {
        mSurfaceView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    public void showSurfaceView() {
        mSurfaceView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
        // to draw.
        try {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            }
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException caused by setPreviewDisplay()", exception);
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.cancelAutoFocus();
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        }
    }


    private Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
        if (sizes == null) return null;

        Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        // Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
        for (Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        // Cannot find the one match the aspect ratio, ignore the requirement
        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }
        return optimalSize;
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        if (holder.getSurface() == null){
          // preview surface does not exist
          return;
        }

        if (mCamera != null) {
            // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
            // the preview.
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
            requestLayout();

            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(mPreviewCallback);
            mCamera.startPreview();
            mCamera.autoFocus(mAutoFocusCallback);
        }
    }

}
```

This is the part I have additionly added to the code but cameraPreviwe disappear as long as I add it.

```
        TextView tvtest = new TextView(context);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,0);
        tvtest.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        tvtest.setText("Сканирайте QR !");
        addView(tvtest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not you add `TextView` in `main.xml` file.
When you programmatically add `SurfaceView` I think it overlap the layout of .xml file that's why your CameraPreview disappear.

Comment: I dont think that this activity have a xml presentation of the layout. What is the main.xml file that you are talking about ?

Comment: I thought that you used `main.xml` as given in example app of ZBar go through that they are using a `TextView` to show the QRCode result.

Comment: The result that they show is really in the activity but I want to set some text over the camera preview not in the result screen

Answer (score 0):

My Idea: You can capture image and set background to a layout and put Textview in that layout, and Capture Screen of Phone.
Good luck.